# Clarification regarding lookup value in the lookup array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was analyzing MATCH function and used the function in the following way:

```
=MATCH(REPT("z",4),Sheet1! G:G)
```

Syntax for MATCH function is `MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])`
Here lookup value is `REPT("z",4)` and lookup array is `Sheet1:G:G`.

`REPT("z",4)` evaluates to "zzzz"

MATCH function is giving me number 21 and it corresponds to last filled row in column G. If I fill the cell G22 then the function gives a value of 22.
Cell G7 already contains the string "zzzz" . My doubt is why I am getting 21 instead of 7 where there is already a matching string.
My level is basic in Excel and request experts help in clarifying whether above situation is meant to find the last filled row in the column or the purpose of match function is to find matching string value in the column range.

[image: Match Function usage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not specifying the match type excel searches for the **last** entry that is **smaller or equal** to the lookup value. In your case, if you put a value (or in your case string) smaller or equal to "zzzz" in the last cell of the row, the formula will return the number of the last row. Therefore, if you don't declare the match type, the lookup array should be sorted ascending. If you want to return the **first** exact match, you should use the match type "exact match".

Comment: Using match type exact is giving row 7 but if we fill smaller or larger than "zzzz" and match type is not specified, it is returning last filled entry only.

Comment: I experimented with different combination of words and found your viewpoint correct. I am accepting your answer. Thanks for your valuable advice.